# Issue with Saving Dark Mode Preference (localStorage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to use localStorage to save the dark mode preference on my website. The issue I am running into is when you switch to dark mode and hit refresh, it stays in dark mode. However, if you switch to dark mode, then back to light mode, and hit refresh, it loads dark mode.

I am stuck so far and haven't been able to find any helpful resources on this yet.

Here is my fiddle along with my js script below.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a0do7pg/)

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul').click(function(){
        $('ul').toggleClass('active')

        let darkThemeEnabled = $('section').toggleClass('dark');

        localStorage.setItem('dark-theme-enabled', darkThemeEnabled);
    })
})

if (localStorage.getItem('dark-theme-enabled')) {
    $('section').toggleClass('dark');

    $('ul').toggleClass('active');  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a Boolean to `localStorage`:

```
$("section").toggleClass("dark");
let darkThemeEnabled = $("section").hasClass("dark");
localStorage.setItem("dark-theme-enabled", darkThemeEnabled);
```

## EDIT

Also change your getting method:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('dark-theme-enabled')) {
    $('section').addClass('dark');
    $('ul').addClass('active');  
}
```

Comment: I just tried adding that and am getting the same result where it remembers the dark mode but when switching to light and refreshing browser, it loads dark mode.

Comment: Sorry, just figured out your problem @trevorc, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hey @jack, I am still getting the same issue with that getting method. I did some more research and adding JSON.parse like this -> 'if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dark-theme-enabled')))' seemed to work for others but when I do it I get an Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token o - Still giving me the same issues of only returning to dark mode.

Comment: @JackBashford I haven't used localStorage much, but it seems like [booleans are stored as strings](https://jsfiddle.net/7149fjnk/6/).

Comment: Yes @ChrisHappy - but they're still truthy, which is how the `if` statement I'm using works.

Comment: @JackBashford I feel like I am totally out of my league here. Here's what I based my comment on: `JSON.stringify( !! 'false' )` outputs `true`

Comment: `'false'` isn't the value `false` itself - it's a string which is truthy. Look up "JavaScript truthy falsy" to find out more.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (i put my dark-mode on my body):

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const checkBox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

window.addEventListener('load', () => {        

    if (!localStorage.dark_mode)
        localStorage.dark_mode = false;

    else if (JSON.parse(localStorage.dark_mode) === true) {
            body.classList.add('dark-mode');
            checkbox.checked = true;
            }
});

checkBox.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');

    if (body.classList.contains('dark-mode')) {
        checkbox.checked = true;
        localStorage.dark_mode = true;
    }
    else {
        checkbox.checked = false;
        localStorage.dark_mode = false;
    }
});
```